# iOS kindle app - where is the anotations file?

Tags: ios, applications, kindle

When using my kindle I can make all manner of annotations, which I can then view on the book I have anotated. This is also true of my kindle iOS app.

However, the kindle itself has a document on it called something like 'my annotations', which constains all the notes I've written on any book (this is handy when the note I've written on the book is something like 'buy milk'), but my iOS kindle app doesn't have this 'my annotations' document. Can someone tell me either how to get the same functionality out of the app, or why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iDevices don't allow direct access to the data files like other tablets which is why you can't see the 'my annotations' file.

However, the iOS version of Kindle app has a nice feature to backup your highlights and annotations to your amazon.com account.  You can enable it by clicking on the Settings (Gear) icon in the lower right corner, select Other, and turn on "Annotations Backup".

Next go to http://kindle.amazon.com and log in with your Amazon account.  Click on the [Your Highlights](https://kindle.amazon.com/your_highlights) link at the top and you will be presented with a list of all your highlights/annotations for all your books.

Comment: That's excellent - although unfortunately it doesn't appear to include those documents I emailed over - pretty good though...

Comment: Ah, a document you emailed to your Kindle is a Personal Document, even if it is called 'my annotations'.  You can manage your documents in [Manage Your Kindle > Personal Documents](https://www.amazon.com/gp/digital/fiona/manage?ie=UTF8&ref_=sa_menu_myk3&#PersonalDocuments)